# Room database with coroutine

Tags: android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In room data base with coroutine when I add suspend key word I get some error
To use Coroutine features, you must add `ktx` artifact from Room as a dependency. androidx.room:room-ktx:

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   suspend fun insertAtDefault(groupNameLocations:ArrayList<GroupNameWithLocation>)